# Set Default Value of a data Extension column using FUEL SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, fuel-sdk, default-value

I am using FUEL sdk to create Data Extensions. I want to set the default value of a column which is a DATE data type to Current Date.

ET_DataExtensionColumn de_col_insertdate = new ET_DataExtensionColumn { Name = "InsertDate", **DefaultValue = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today)**,  FieldType = DataExtensionFieldType.Date, IsRequired = true };

This is not creating the data extension as the field type is DATE.

If I am not using Convert.ToString, I am getting an error - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string' as DefaultValue is String type.

If I pass the DefaultValue as "04/06/2018" and remove the FieldType = DataExtensionFieldType.Date, it's creating the data extension but its no longer DATE datatype.

Please let me know if anyone was able to successfully set the default value of a DATE datatype field to current date using fuel sdk.